# How to create function generator by passing string parameter in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, function, dynamic

I want to pass string parameter to function and get object with this key.

```
function getFunction(name: string): { [name]: () => number } {
  return {
    [name]: () => {
      console.log(1);
      return 2;
    },
  };
}

const { myName } = getFunction("myName");
```

In rtk query createApi generating hooks by endpoints property. I want to do it with typescript.

```
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react'
import type { Pokemon } from './types'

// Define a service using a base URL and expected endpoints
export const pokemonApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: 'pokemonApi',
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/' }),
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getPokemonByName: builder.query<Pokemon, string>({
      query: (name) => `pokemon/${name}`,
    }),
  }),
})

// Export hooks for usage in functional components, which are
// auto-generated based on the defined endpoints
export const { useGetPokemonByNameQuery } = pokemonApi
```

Comment: What do you want to get? a *named* function? A `getFunction<T>`?

Comment: How it's done in rtk query? https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/overview It's generating functions by object name.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `name:string`to it.

```
function getFunction(name: string): { [name: string]: () => number } {
  return {
    [name]: () => {
      console.log(1);
      return 2;
    },
  };
}

const { myName } = getFunction("myName");
```

Comment: I think OP wants something more narrow in terms of the type the key can have for the returned object . With this code this `const { myAge } = getFunction("myName");` is valid, even though the object will only have `myName` as a property and `myAge` will be `undefined`. My understanding is that OP would want something like that to be invalid and only allow you to destructure `myName`

Comment: In rtk query createApi generating hooks by our endpoints object. I wont to do something like that